# GraphQL Ajax Get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to figure out how to write a graphQL Ajax GET request.
When I type in the [complete url](https://oql98jj5d4.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/query?query=%7B%20book(id:%229789024576807%22)%20%7B%20bol%20%7B%20id%20%7D%20itunes%20%7B%20beschikbaar%20%7D%20%7D%7D) in my browser I do get back data.

However, when I want to try to get the data via a Ajax GET method:

```
$.get({
  url: 'https://ltbliqkb1c.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thomas/query?query=%7B%20book(id:%229789024576807%22)%20%7B%20bol%20%7B%20id%20%7D%20itunes%20%7B%20beschikbaar%20%7D%20%7D%7D',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain:true,
     headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://ltbliqkb1c.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    }

}).done(function(response) {
  console.log('Data:', response.data);
});
```

I'm getting a:

> Failed to load
>   https://ltbliqkb1c.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thomas/query?query=%7B%20book(id:%229789024576807%22)%20%7B%20bol%20%7B%20id%20%7D%20itunes%20%7B%20beschikbaar%20%7D%20%7D%7D:
>   Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**My Graphql query:**

```
{
  book(id: "9789024576791") {
    bol {
      id
    }
    itunes {
      beschikbaar
    }
  }
}
```

**I've also tried the following js:**

```
var test =  JSON.stringify('{book(id:"9789047202363"){bol{id}}}')
$.ajax({
     method: "GET",
          url: "https://ltbliqkb1c.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thomas/query?"+test,
          contentType: "application/json",
          crossDomain:true,
          success: function(data) {     
               console.log('data',data);
          },
          error: function(err) {
               console.log(err);
          }
});
```

And with the following variable to stringify:

```
var test= ` book($id: String!){
              bol{
                id,
                ean,
                mobileUrl,
                desktopUrl
              }
              itunes{
                beschikbaar
                auteur
                titel
              }
            }
          }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set headers to answer as `access-control-allow-origin:*`

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.